# Change TD Element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a webpage with announcements which pulls from the database. Here is my HTML code

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
   <tr>
      <td id="maintitle" style="font-size: 34px; font-weight: bold;"><?php print  $row['title'];   ?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="maincontent"><?php print $row['content'];?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="mainname" style="font-size: 12px; font-style: italic;"><?php print $row['name'];?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

What I want, is for the TD element to display a particular text if there are not announcements and I've decided to use jQuery for that. Here is my code for it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#maintitle',this).each(function(){
         if($(this).html() != '');
            $(this).append("No Incidents recorded!");
      });
   });
</script>
```

However, even when there are no announcements in database, nothing happens. I was wondering if there is a different way to go about it, or changing the jquery code.

Comment: Your html is invalid. you're outputting the **SAME** id values for all of your query results. An `id` must be unique across the entire document.

Comment: and `$document` should be `$(document)`

Comment: There are multiple problems with the above code. You're using the same ID across multiple elements. This is semantically incorrect. I believe your selector is also incorrect `$('#maintitle, this')`. I'm not sure what's trying to be accomplished here. The `this` seems inappropriate here. Finally, your `if` statement has a terminating `;`. No matter if the statement is true or false `$(this).append("No Incients recorded!");` will always execute. `this` in this context will be the current `#maintitle` element being iterated through. I don't believe this is the desired behavior either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this a code you want -- you have to loop through tr not td

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('table tr').each(function(){
          if($(this).find('td').html() == ''){
            $(this).find('td').html("No Incidents recorded!");
          }
      });
   });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/azzfct04/)

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I had issues in the beginning, but it was because of how my PHP was coded. The way it was set up, it was preventing HTML from creating any tables if the database was empty. I changed it a bit, and now it works flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your jQuery script is doing an absolute opposite of what you want (if I understood your question correctly) - it appends the text if there IS a value in the  element. The main *logic* problem is in the if statement:

```
if($(this).html != '');
    $(this).append("No Incidents recorded!");
```

...and that says *"if the inner html in the element is NOT empty - append the string..."*

It should be:

```
if($(this).html() === '') {
    $(this).append("No Incidents recorded!");
}
```

I should point out other problems with your code even if it's not related to the question:

- As Mark B pointed out in the comment you are outputting the same `id` values in every iteration of the loop ([W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)). Solution - use the `class` attribute.
- You're terminating the `if` statement immediately so it has no effect on the following code:

  ```
  if($(this).html != '');
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  if($(this).html() === '') {
      // execute this code when the if statement resolves to true.
  }
  ```
- This line in your script is wrong because you need to call the `$` function and what you are doing is referencing the `$document` variable *which does not exist in jQuery*:

  ```
  $document.ready(function(){
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  ```
- You don't really need a second argument (`this`) in the jQuery function here, because passing `this` as a context makes no sense here:

  ```
  $('#title',this).each(function(){
  ```
- You should add parentheses after html, because it's a function - not a property:

  ```
  if($(this).html != '');
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  if($(this).html() ...
  ```

Some more points to consider (not much of an error, just some tips):

- Use alternative syntax when using loops or other php constructs combined with html (just makes code much cleaner):

  ```
  <?php while(expression):?>
  <a href="#">example link</a>
  ...
  <?php endwhile ?>
  ```
- Use a shorthand version of `<?php echo ... ?>` or `<?php print ... ?>`:

  ```
  <?= 'some string...' ?>
  ```

Happy coding!

Comment: This answer will also generate a syntax error as `html` should be `html()`. It's a function not an object property...

Comment: You are right! I completely ignored that. However, even after changing the jQuery code, it still doesn't do anything. I changed the element id and gave them unique name as well. I even changed the .html to .html()

Comment: @NimitDesai See the above comment about the syntax error. It's `.html()` not `.html`...

Comment: @War10ck I did. I didn't receive any error, however, still empty page.

Comment: @NimitDesai Did you also correct the error pointed out by _@briansol_ above? `$(document)` instead of `$document`? What does your browser console say? Remember JavaScript errors will not display on the page but instead in the browser's console.

Comment: @War10ck Yes I did. Here is my new code 

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#maintitle',this).each(function(){
  if($(this).html() === '');
   $(this).append("No Incidents recorded!");
  });
 });

The console doesn't say anything about the script for some reason.

Comment: I have updated the original post with the new code after correcting the syntax issues.

Comment: The core premise here is still wrong. _"and that says "if the inner html in the element is NOT empty - append the string..."_ is incorrect. The `if` statement has a terminating `;`. That says, no matter if this is `true` or `false` execute the append statement. The conditional does absolutely nothing here.